# Current prevalence of idiom "pulling for you"

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, dialects

A prior question asks about the [origin of the phrase "pulling for you,"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197857/origin-of-phrase-pulling-for-you) a phrase that conveys well-wishes and support ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%20for)):

> US, informal
>
> : to say or show that one hopes (someone or something) will succeed, get well, etc.
>
> > We're all pulling for you (to get well).
> >
> > I'm pulling for the home team.

Today, I am more interested in the recent prevalence of the idiom "pulling for you." Basically, is it generally known across the US, as Merriam-Webster suggests, or is it now more common in more or fewer dialects? Would it be recognized or used in another country's dialect, like in a British, Canadian, Indian, or Irish context?

When I used the term recently, I realized I don't have a sense of how common or widespread the turn of phrase is. As for the Merriam-Wesbter note, I wonder if it's outdated. I have come across examples of non-US usage, like the BBC using the expression to describe the crowd during Ian Woosnam's 1991 Masters run:

> The partisan crowd were once again **pulling for** Watson as Woosnam's ball disappeared under water. (James Pontin. "[The Masters: Ian Woosnam Recalls His 1991 Augusta Triumph, 30 Years On](https://www.bbc.com/sport/golf/56596909)." BBC Sport Wales, 7 April 2021.)

So it's conceivable the usage has spread beyond the US, but I hope someone can answer more definitively.

Comment: Try "pull for the team" on BBC Sport. It's common enough. And here: It really isn't pleasant or sensible to do nothing or ignore the obvious. The consequences could be dreadful, focused without distractions we all pull for the team. https://www.toffeeweb.com/season/22-23/news/43226.html The problem with questions like this is that it places the burden on those who answer since only googling etc. will provide any proof of anything. I just found it in Ireland but I am not prepared to search: site:.ca, site:.in, site:nz, to mention a few.

Comment: Be brave rather than common or widespread, as we're pulling for you.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Pulling for you or rooting for you means to stand behind someone, to support them in their endeavors.

Comment: I meant that we can use a term without worrying that it's common or not.

Comment: [This usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We%27re+all+pulling+for%2CWe%27re+all+rooting+for%2CWe%27re+all+praying+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests to me that *We're all **pulling** for you* gained traction during WW2, but since then it's been eclipsed by ***...praying / rooting** for you*.

Comment: Usage examples for “pull for” from late 19th c. till recent  years are all from AmE https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/nx2h44i#y3evv7y

Answer (score 3):

While it is used in the UK, "rooting for someone/thing/team" is more common than "pulling for someone/thing/team."

"Rooting" is like cheering the team on, hoping for them as opposed to "pulling" which is like a short form of "pulling together" implying some form of actual involvement towards the outcome.

Perhaps "pulling" is less common now as in some places it can have a vulgar meaning.